# Do different Coordinate Systems refer to the same elements?

Tags: coordinate-systems

Wikipedia defines the [*Real Coordinate Space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_coordinate_space#Definition_and_uses) as follows:

> For any natural number $n$, the set $\mathbb{R}^n$ consists of all n-tuples of real numbers ($\mathbb{R}$). It is called (the) $n$-dimensional real space

Now, let $C_i, 1 ≤ i ≤ n$, be $n$ sets. Wikipedia defines a [*coordinate space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_space#Definition) of $n$ dimensions as a set $S$ together with a surjective partial mapping $$ \varphi : C_1 \times \dots \times C_n \to S $$

If I understand it correctly, converting one Coordinate system into  another, e.g. Cartesian coordinates into Spherical coordinates is just using sets that are different to $C_i, 1 ≤ i ≤ n$ together with a different mapping $\varphi$. However, *both* coordinate systems still index the same set of elements e.g. the elements from $S$ or the elements / tupels from $\mathbb{R}^n$

**Q:** Is my assumption that two different coordinate system can refere to the same set of elements correct or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even if you work with *one* space, a coordinating system could vary.

$\mathbb{R}^n$ as a real vector space it is already parametrized by itself, $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is identity and therefore could be omitted. On the other hand, when more general vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ is given, then coordinate system that is also linear isomorphism is substantial: $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\to V$. Note, that any $n\times n$ invertible matrix $M$ yields new coordinate system $\phi \circ M:\mathbb{R}^n\to V$ that is also an isomorphism.

In calculus switch between polar and cartesian coordinate system can help with solving integral. Interesting example is [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral): $\int e^{-x^2}dx$. Indefinite integral can not be expessed in terms of elementary functions, but $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt\pi$ and the proof uses polar coordinates.

Both spherical and cylindrical coordinate spaces describe the same set: $\mathbb{R}^3$.

By these examples I've tried to compensate vague wikipedia article, that you have mentioned. With definition that broad nearly everything is coordinate space: permutation of a set, group epimorphism, projection, n-ary relation, graph coloring etc. From my experience "coordinates" always means "elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or $\mathbb{R}$ in particular)", but it's just an opinion.